# Codename one scrollbar coming back

Tags: codenameone

Scrollbar coming back when I send new Android build. I was add this code to hide scrollbar and everything fine, I didn't change anything.

```
UIManager.getInstance().setLookAndFeel(new DefaultLookAndFeel(UIManager.getInstance()) {
                @Override
                public void bind(Component cmp) {
                    if (cmp instanceof Container) {
                        cmp.setScrollVisible(false);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why this fails but a better approach would be defining the theme constant `scrollVisibleBool=false`.

Comment: Shouldn't the constant scrollVisibleBool appear in the constants drop down in the Theme Editor? In order to define this theme constant I had to add it manually to the theme.xml file. Is there a more proper way to add the constant? http://imgur.com/a/KtveZ

Comment: Also, is the scrollVisibleBool constant undocumented? I could not find any thing about it in the dev guide.

Comment: You can type it in. It seems that this did slip thru the cracks and isn't documented. I'll try and add it.